# showing error: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client on terminal

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Node.js version: v18.15.0
mongoose: 7.1.1

When I send data through PostMan, it saves everything well and does its job, but I get this error on the console.

```
app.post('/product', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const singleProduct = await product.create(req.body)
        res.sendStatus(200).json(singleProduct)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        res.sendStatus(500).json({ message: error.message })
    }
```

Ater posting data through postman it shows following error

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:663:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (F:\nodejsproject\crudapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (F:\nodejsproject\crudapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:624:15)
    at ServerResponse.sendStatus (F:\nodejsproject\crudapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:373:8)
    at F:\nodejsproject\crudapp\server.js:20:20
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

Comment: it is not returning and trying to set headers again (sendStatus). the question is where

Comment: try replacing `res.sendStatus(200).json(singleProduct)` with `res.sendStatus(200).json({singleProduct})`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
app.post('/product', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const singleProduct = await product.create(req.body)
    res.status(200).json(singleProduct)
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(401).json({ message: error.message })
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. In the first place, it's very hard to see what exactly was changed and there's no explanation *why* it was changed.